# javascript d3 culling d3 values outside of clippath

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a timeline graphic where the x axis is time and the y axis is a discriminator value from a column selected out of a csv.

It essentially pulls out the unique values from the key column and sets it up as its own row on the y-axis

[image]

In the above example the random digits on the left are unique values from a column.  The reason I do this is because I want all timerange values using the same unique key to appear on the same row.

I am struggling with latency right now as I test it out,  There are 6000 unique keys that are all being displayed (if you pan down more appear).  What I'd like in order to maintain speed is to completely cull any values that aren't within the clip-path rectangle set.

As an example, there are currently 6000 group nodes with thousands more rectangles within the dom that aren't visible or being drawn.  The updating of the translation of all these values are causing the serious lag.

Is there an efficient way to effectively test only for values within the clip-path range and enter/exit them such that only what would be visible is actually being drawn?  I'm essentially looking for a way to completely cull the dom nodes out to speed the process up.

Comment: I'd probably solve this problem by implementing simple paging, which would slice the current page + size out of data array and pass only that into the chart

Comment: when you pan filter the data based on the domain of the y-axis and enter-exit-modify the existing rows

Comment: @rioV8 I was thinking about it lastnight and came to the same solution, that I'd likely have to do an enter/exit of data within x distance of the clip-path edges to cull